# access a javascript global variable from managed bean jsf2

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, managed-bean

is there a way to access a javascript global variable from managed bean :

```
    var id = "";

        function affecter(id){
            $("#affecterHidden").val(id);
            alert(id);
        }


<h:inputHidden value="#{typeMB.selectedType.idtype}" id="affecterHidden" />
```

I wanted to use `f:setpropertyActionListener` but it doesn't match to my goal

Comment: What's your goal?You wanted to use `f:setpropertyActionListener` instead of 'inputHidden'

Comment: I want to access a global javascript variable from managed bean

Comment: Javascript runs on the client side, your managed bean on the server side. There is no way of accessing a Javascript variable, except you pass the value to the bean as well, like any other parameter.